# Sample Image Capture with Scanner to Yosemite

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, image-scanner, osx-yosemite

I tested the code page of Apple developers and does not work I nose if it is special because I'm testing on Mac osx Yosemite because when I try to view the scanners connected not show me none, but instead if you use the software company the scanner performs scanning me well, I would like someone to please could provide me an example that works in Yosemite to know where to begin and whether this well developed in Yosemite.

Comment: I found this answer check it


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339108/ikscannerdeviceview-is-only-working-once/31121313#31121313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding that does not recognize your printer Yosemite , try the following
[No more scanning after upgrading to MacOS X 10.10](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Mac-Printing-and-Scanning/No-more-scanning-after-upgrading-to-MacOS-X-10-10-quot/td-p/4625652)

Comment: If served me thank you very much , I could finally see how scanner to scan and i look my image